# Is there any ways to define 2-tuples in one line?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm not expierenced in python.
I need to define field 'year' with range restriction. Now i'm using this code, but I think there exists shorten way to do this.

```
YEAR_CHOICE = []
for year in range(2020,1899,-1):
   YEAR_CHOICE += [(year, year)]
year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Year', choices=YEAR_CHOICE, default=0)
```

Is therу any ways to define 2-tuples in one line? May be I can make field what I need in other way? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look at using a [**list comprehension**](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/mapping_lists.html):

```
YEAR_CHOICE = [(year,year) for year in xrange(2020,1899,-1)]
```

You should also usage `xrange` instead of `range`.  `xrange` is preferred as it returns the values one by one rather than creating the whole list.

Comment: For those who may not have seen the term before, search for "list comprehension"

Comment: Or click on the link added to my answer.

Comment: xrange() is preferred usage up to python 2.6. xrange() is discontinued in python 3.0 and range() performs in 3.0 as xrange() did in previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

[zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) the range with itself:

```
YEAR_CHOICE = zip(*[range(2020,1899,-1)]*2)
```

or use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
YEAR_CHOICE = [(year,year) for year in range(2020,1899,-1)]
```

Comment: The zip code is clever, but even an experienced Python programming would need to think about it for a few moments to discern what it's actually doing and why it works.  I'd personally recommend the longer but clearer list comprehension.

Comment: Yeah, zip(*[range(2020,1899,-1)]*2) is zip(range(2020,1899,-1),range(2020,1899,-1))